# Sync Framework updates regist on insert action

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-sync-framework, syncfx

I have a Scope that only takes effect on some range of regists, 
(for example the range of regists which IDs are between 1 and 3)

So, lets assume that i have the following regist on remote database:

### ID --- Name

1 ---  Name1

2 ---  Name2

3 ---  Name3

4 ---  Name4

5 ---  Name5

On my client, if i make changes in regists which id is 1, 2 or 3 (that bellongs to the scope) the synchronization works OK.

But if I add a new row at client database with ID 4, this regist will overlap the regist with the same ID at remote database and any king of failed event is thrown.

Why this happens ? 
Since the ID already exists in remote database, the regist shouldn be inserted right?

This is my server provisioning:

```
DbSyncScopeDescription scopeTemplateDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(TemplateForNames);
        scopeTemplateDesc.UserComment = "Template test";

        DbSyncTableDescription NamesDescription =
            SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Names", ServerConn);


        scopeTemplateDesc.Tables.Add(NamesDescription);
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverTemplate =
            new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(ServerConn, scopeTemplateDesc, SqlSyncScopeProvisioningType.Template);


        serverTemplate.Tables["Names"].AddFilterColumn("IDName");
        serverTemplate.Tables["Names"].FilterClause = @"[side].[IDName] in
                                                                        ( 
                                                                            1,2,3
                                                                        )";
        try
        {
            serverTemplate.Apply();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("...");
        }

        // Scope
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverDBProvisiong = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(ServerConn);
        serverDBProvisiong.PopulateFromTemplate("ScopeNamesParaUtilizador", TemplateForNames);

        serverDBProvisiong.UserComment = "Scope para o utilizador sincronizar os seus nomes";

        if (!serverDBProvisiong.ScopeExists("ScopeNamesParaUtilizador"))
        {
            try
            {
                serverDBProvisiong.Apply();
            }
            catch (Exception) { Console.WriteLine("..."); }
        }
```

This code is for local database:

```
DbSyncScopeDescription serverScopeDescForBranch
            = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope("ScopeNamesParaUtilizador", ServerConn);

        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning branchProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(ClientConn, serverScopeDescForBranch);
        if (!branchProvision.ScopeExists("ScopeNamesParaUtilizador"))
        {
            branchProvision.Apply();
        }
```

And this is synchronization code:

```
SqlSyncProvider remoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ScopeNamesParaUtilizador", ServerConn);
        SqlSyncProvider localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ScopeNamesParaUtilizador", ClientConn);

        SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
        syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = localProvider;
        syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = remoteProvider;

        syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

        ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed +=
                new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(SynchronizationBusinessRules_ApplyChangeFailed);

        ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider).ApplyChangeFailed +=
            new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(SynchronizationBusinessRules_ApplyChangeFailed);
        try
        {
            SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

            Console.WriteLine("Start Time: " + syncStats.SyncStartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Uploaded: " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Downloaded: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Complete Time: " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

static void SynchronizationBusinessRules_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Conflict.ErrorMessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your client and sync doesn't know about the existing row in the server, so the change is uploaded to the server. the sync would fail for the row already exist (assuming the id is your PK) and you will get a conflict (insert - insert)

you have to handle it and tell sync what to do with it, apply row from client or retain row in server.

it's not a good idea to be using identity IDs as PKs if you're doing synchronization. Not unless you do ID partitioning (client gets 1-100,000, client 2, 100,001 to 200,000, etc...)

Comment: Yes, the ID is my PK. But i dont get the insert conflict, the local inserted row overlaps the row at remote database

Comment: show the code how you're synching and handling the conflict. also, you said you have records 1-5 on the server, you made changes to records 1-3 on the client, where did 1-3 come from?

Comment: I populate server database with 5 records, than i sincronize the 3 first records with my client (records affected by scope). Than i added more records on client database with the ID of 4, 5, etc, and after sincronize this new records any failure event was thrown and remote records are overlaped

Comment: I have another question related to this,
Is it possible that the stored procedure that inserts record also updates the ones that already exists ??

Comment: nope, that should fire a conflict first. where's the code for your ApplyChangeFailed event handler? also, can you enable tracing in verbose mode?

Comment: I insert the method above but it only contains some debug code